# Is there an easy way to make part of an NSString object a superscript or subscript?

Tags: cocoa, macos, nsstring

For example, suppose I have an NSString @"20O(2H,1H)19O", and I want all the numbers to be superscript.  Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you probably want [`NSAttributedString`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html) with [`NSSuperScriptAttributeName`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSAttributedString_AppKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSSuperscriptAttributeName).  If you need to keep it in an `NSString`, [unicode](http://www.unicode.org/charts/) has characters for [superscripted digits](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2070.pdf).

Comment: UPDATE: I ended up using an NSMutableAttributedString.  Apple's documentations is quite wanting, though, so I didn't get much out of it.  I ended up following the examples in Aaron Hillegass's "Cocoa Programming For Mac OS X".  It was actually quite a chore, as I had to keep track of the exact character positions of the bits that I wanted to superscript.  Details of what I did can be found in the source code for AppController.m, in the method generateFormattedReactionString, from my project at http://code.google.com/p/mac-helios-sim/, in case anyone is curious.

Comment: Note that `NSSuperscriptAttributeName` takes an integer, though. This allows only for pretty coarse adjustments where you want the superscript (or subscript) be positions.

Answer (score 3):

This function should return a given number in superscript. Very simple

```
-(NSString *)superScriptOf:(NSString *)inputNumber{

    NSString *outp=@"";
    for (int i =0; i<[inputNumber length]; i++) {
    unichar chara=[inputNumber characterAtIndex:i] ;
    switch (chara) {
        case '1':
            NSLog(@"1");
            outp=[outp stringByAppendingFormat:@"\u00B9"];
            break;
        case '2':
            NSLog(@"2");
            outp=[outp stringByAppendingFormat:@"\u00B2"];
            break;
        case '3':
            NSLog(@"3");
            outp=[outp stringByAppendingFormat:@"\u00B3"];
            break;
        case '4':
            NSLog(@"4");
            outp=[outp stringByAppendingFormat:@"\u2074"];
            break;
        case '5':
            NSLog(@"5");
                            outp=[outp stringByAppendingFormat:@"\u2075"];
            break;
        case '6':
            NSLog(@"6");
                            outp=[outp stringByAppendingFormat:@"\u2076"];
            break;
        case '7':
            NSLog(@"7");
            outp=[outp stringByAppendingFormat:@"\u2077"];
            break;
        case '8':
            NSLog(@"8");
            outp=[outp stringByAppendingFormat:@"\u2078"];
            break;
        case '9':
            NSLog(@"9");
            outp=[outp stringByAppendingFormat:@"\u2079"];
            break;
        case '0':
            NSLog(@"0");
            outp=[outp stringByAppendingFormat:@"\u2070"];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
return outp;   
}
```

Given an input string of numbers it just returns the equivalent superscript string.