# Add a string as a subscript in another string

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsstring

I want to append a string as subscript to another string using Objective C. Does anyone know how can I do this?

Comment: What does "as subscript" mean?  Do you want it to display on the screen as a subscript, or do you want to be in square brackets like an array subscript?

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3525435/is-there-an-easy-way-to-make-part-of-an-nsstring-object-a-superscript-or-subscri

Comment: Could you provide example ? As I understand you have "some good string"

Answer (score 2):

If you mean *suffix*, here's how:

```
NSString *foobar = [@"foo" stringByAppendingString:@"bar"];
```

Comment: Subscript doesn't mean anything in the context of a string. subscript is a typographic effect. You could add a subscript to a label, or to an NSAttributedString, but not to an NSString.

Comment: Subscript is ambiguous. You are assuming one particular meaning (a numeric subscript), but the question doesn't make that clear. He could mean any arbitrary text as a subscript.

Comment: Yeah I can use unicode for each char or number but it would be a very lengthy process, coz for each and every possibility I have to write one condition.